# Save all of terminal display while in shell script without using tee

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I saw in a previous question that putting `exec > >(tee -ai file)` will capture every thing that is displayed in the script while still showing it. This works but, being able to just "snap-shot" whats displayed in the terminal with out recording it all the time would work better

Comment: There are dedicated terminals like `tmux` that can do exactly this (snapshotting the current screen's content), but you need to be actually using a terminal with that capability. In general, it's the terminal's job to keep track of what's stored at each location on the screen -- no other program even has enough information to tell, because other things started before/after/by it can write to the TTY themselves.

Comment: ...which is to say, if when you say you want to save *all* of the display you're including content that was written before the script started, nothing except dedicated terminal support -- not `nohup`, not `script`, etc -- is up to the task.

Comment: Keep in mind that the TTY interface was built with a serial interface in mind -- if you look at the capabilities of 1970s equipment like the [DEC VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100), that's the core of the interface we have today. Writing content to a TTY is, well, writing content *to* a TTY; a query/readback facility to ask the TTY to tell the computer on the other end of the wire (again, traditionally, a completely separate piece of hardware!) what's currently being displayed never was standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things you can do here:

1. you can simple set the output to a file like:

   `bash printer.sh > saving_file`

Note: if you already have a file called saving_file from the previous session use **>>** (append the new output to the existing file without overwriting the existing data) instead of **>** (will overwrite anything stored previously will be lost)

2. you can use nohup:

   `nohup bash printer.sh`

both of these commands will save everything that is output of the script.

3. Third thing you can do is you can just make use of the `script` command, simply do a:

   `script saving_file`

so whatever you will do in your terminal after the script command will be saved to a file called saving_file. if you want to stop sending everything from the terminal simply do an `exit` and you will be using terminal normally.

you can use nohup and writing to a file from within a shell script as well, if you are asking for something other than that then I will recommend using something like the following code.

```
var=$(echo 'hello world')
echo $var > saving_file # this will write 'hello world' to a file named saving _file

echo $var # this will display hello world
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, I want to put something in my shell script that will put everything displayed on the screen into a file, not changing the contents of the file till this "mystery command" is called again

Comment: @Geremachek2 you mean everything displayed before a particular line in shell script ?

Comment: something like that, Image it as taking a picture, not a video if you get what I'm saying

Comment: @Geremachek2 can u give like an example code, abstract like echo 30 something  and then u want everything that was displayed up until that point saved. it will be helpful in precisely giving you what you want

Comment: echo Hello, World
saveterm test.txt
echo This won't be saved

cat test.txt
Hello, World

Comment: @Geremachek2 you want to save it and save it to a file ?

Comment: if you just want to do that just do a `echo Hello > saving_file`

Comment: @Geremachek2 checkout the last part of updated answer